# How to concatenate two tuples

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

Concatenate two tuples like list are done in python3

```py
lis2 = [[23, [2,34]]]
lis = [[2, [2,3]]]
lis + lis2 = [[2, [2, 3]], [23, [2, 34]]]

tup2 = (((3, (234,))))
tup = (((2, (324,234))))
tup + tup2 = (2, (324, 234), 3, (234,))
```

How to create new tuples with contents:
((2, (324,234)), (3, 234,)) like I can get with list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that tuples don't add like lists do; the problem is that `tup2` and `tup` aren't what you think they are.  Putting parentheses around a single item does *not* make a tuple with one item.  To do that, you need to add a comma at the end.  Thus, you need:

```
tup2 = (((3, (234,))),)
tup = (((2, (324,234))),)
```

Then `tup+tup2` will be what you expect.

Comment: @Guimoute: Not clear what you mean; why not just add it yourself as a comment?